# Filter and sort Commerce products based on Matrix blocks

Tags: plugin-development, matrix, plugin-craftcommerce2, query, products

We have a website that uses Craft CMS v3.1.28 and Commerce v2.1.6.1. The below logic is implemented within a plugin and we're prepared to do custom implementations aka. prepared to go deep!

**I would like to extend an existing ProductQuery with two innerJoins on a Matrix field**. The matrix blocks represent product groups (by title; "contain") and sets the order of the product groups. I am currently getting duplicate rows (see code in first answer). I think I might have to innerJoin on the subQuery (generated below)..?

Now, we're currently using the code below to get the products and it works. However, it's not very efficient, **since we then have to loop through the matrix and match by title to get the right order**.

```
// $base_product_titles is the array of titles from the matrix blocks  
// this query is obviously done per category
// additionally we have some filters ($types and $variant_criteria)

$base_products_query = Product::find()
        ->relatedTo($category)
        ->title($base_product_titles)
        ->type($types)
        ->hasVariant($variant_criteria)
        ->orderBy('type')
        ->with([
            'usage',
            'casing',
            'series',
            'defaultVariant',
            'variants',
            'variants.tire_size',
            [
                'variants.images',
                [ 'withTransforms' => ['product_overview']]
            ]
        ]);
```

PS: We group the above result by title in the template using |group('title').

I would appreciate any guidance!

Kind regards,
Meinhard

Answer (score 1):

I've tried the following, but it "obviously" gives me duplicate rows and my SQL and Craft/Yii knowledge isn't good enough to solve it. It's basically its own subquery with no relation to the "filters" in the query above, except for the title. I'm thinking that I could innerJoin on the initial subquery (which is the query/result from above) but don't know how ($base_products_query->subQuery equals NULL)?

```
$base_products_query->innerJoin('`craft_matrixblocks`', "`craft_matrixblocks`.`ownerId` = '".$category->id."' AND `craft_matrixcontent_product_sorting`.`elementId` = `craft_matrixblocks`.`id`");    
$base_products_query->innerJoin('`craft_matrixcontent_product_sorting`', '`content`.`title` = `craft_matrixcontent_product_sorting`.`field_product_product_title`);
$base_products_query->orderBy('craft_matrixblocks.sortOrder');
```